C# WinForms timer is stuck/hangs while creating my Office.Interop.PowerPoint
Creating PowerPoint presentations in C# Visual Studio, I realized that my WinForm timer hangs; I can't even move my Application around the screen. Is there a way to create my PowerPoint in the background?
To illustrate the issue, I have this code example in "C:\myPowerPointHangs\" for C# Windows Forms .NET
I have added from Reference Manager>COM>Type Libraries the assembly reference "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library" (Version 2.8), or also from NuGet: "Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint" (Version 15.0.4420.1018) added to my project...
I have created two Timers.

Timer1 will show 100ms steps counting in the caption of my WinForm, and it will start Timer2 at 2000 milliseconds then continue counting.

Timer2 runs once. It creates the slide and the matrix of boxes. This takes several seconds. Finally, it saves the presentation. After that, my WinForm is alive again.


// Project>Add Reference>COM>Type Libraries>Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
// Tools>NuGet Package Manager>Manage NuGet Packages for solution>Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint 15.0.4420.1018
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using State = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myPowerPointHangs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        readonly float u = 72.0f; // Inches
        int t = 0;
        int t0 { get => (++t); set => t = 0; }
        string fileName = @"C:\myPowerPointHangs\mySlides.ppt";
        public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); timer1.Start(); }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            this.Text = t0.ToString() + "00ms";
            if (t == 20) timer2.Start();
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
            PowerPoint.Application pptApplication = new PowerPoint.Application();
            PowerPoint.Presentation ppt;
            PowerPoint.Slide slide;
            PowerPoint.Slides slides;
            Office.MsoAutoShapeType shape;
            ppt = pptApplication.Presentations.Add(State.msoTrue);
            slides = ppt.Slides;
            slides.Application.Caption = "mySlides";
            slide = slides.Add(1, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank);
            shape = Office.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeFlowchartTerminator;

            float left = 6.61f * u;
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
            {
                float top = 0.1f * u;
                for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++)
                {
                    slide.Shapes.AddShape(shape, left, top, 0.77f * u, 0.23f * u);
                    int i = slide.Shapes.Count;
                    slide.Shapes[i].Fill.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToWin32(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                    slide.Shapes[i].Line.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToWin32(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(58, 58, 58));
                    slide.Shapes[i].TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToWin32(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(19, 40, 79));
                    slide.Shapes[i].TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 6.0f;
                    slide.Shapes[i].TextFrame.WordWrap = State.msoFalse;
                    slide.Shapes[i].TextFrame.TextRange.Text = col.ToString("00")+row.ToString("00");
                    top += slide.Shapes[i].Height + 0.02f * u;
                }
                left += slide.Shapes[slide.Shapes.Count].Width + 0.05f * u;
            }

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName)) System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
            ppt.SaveAs(fileName, PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPresentation, Office.MsoTriState.msoCTrue);
            ppt.Close();
        }
    }
}

There are similar topics here and there, but do not address my question: how to run Office.Interop.PowerPoint in the background without hanging my WinForm application?
In addition, if for any reason we open a popup message in the PowerPoint App before or while creating the presentation, it generates an Exception as:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Call was rejected by callee. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 

Opening_PowerPoint_Popup => Call_was_rejected_by_callee

Yes, of course. It is dealing with the file. For the most easy way you can use a backgroundworker or change your code to use async await. BackGroundWorker

Paul, could you please write an example from my code and make it an Answer?

You can write a simple void function and use multi-threading to create a new thread for power point process.
Notice: First you need to create timer1 manually.
// Project>Add Reference>COM>Type Libraries>Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
// Tools>NuGet Package Manager>Manage NuGet Packages for solution>Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint 15.0.4420.1018
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using State = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace myPowerPointHangs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); timer1.Start(); }
        
        readonly float u = 72.0f; // Inches
        int t = 0;
        string fileName = @"C:\myPowerPointHangs\mySlides.ppt";
        int cnt = 0;
        Thread trd;

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Text=cnt.ToString() + "00ms";
            if (cnt++ >= 20) { cnt = 0; trd = new Thread(power_point); trd.Start(); timer1.Stop(); }
        }

        void power_point()
        {
            PowerPoint.Application pptApplication = new PowerPoint.Application();
            PowerPoint.Presentation ppt;
            PowerPoint.Slide slide;
            PowerPoint.Slides slides;
            Office.MsoAutoShapeType shape;
            ppt = pptApplication.Presentations.Add(State.msoTrue);
            slides = ppt.Slides;
            slides.Application.Caption = "mySlides";
            slide = slides.Add(1, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank);
            shape = Office.MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeFlowchartTerminator;

            float left = 6.61f * u;
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
            {
                float top = 0.1f * u;
                for (int row = 0; row < 20; row++)
                {
                    slide.Shapes.AddShape(shape, left, top, 0.77f * u, 0.23f * u);
                    int i = slide.Shapes.Count;
                    slide.Shapes[i].Fill.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToWin32(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                    slide.Shapes[i].Line.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToWin32(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(58, 58, 58));
                    slide.Shapes[i].TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToWin32(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(19, 40, 79));
                    slide.Shapes[i].TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 6.0f;
                    slide.Shapes[i].TextFrame.WordWrap = State.msoFalse;
                    slide.Shapes[i].TextFrame.TextRange.Text = col.ToString("00") + row.ToString("00");
                    top += slide.Shapes[i].Height + 0.02f * u;
                }
                left += slide.Shapes[slide.Shapes.Count].Width + 0.05f * u;
            }

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileName)) System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
            ppt.SaveAs(fileName, PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsPresentation, Office.MsoTriState.msoCTrue);
            ppt.Close();
            trd.Abort();
        }

    }
}


Thanks AmirABD, I needed to make changes to your code since the intention of timer1 is to show the counting while the PowerPoint is created. Your thread approach worked fine.
        public Form1()
       {
            InitializeComponent();
            timer1.Start();
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Text = cnt.ToString() + "00ms";
            if (cnt++ == 20) { trd = new Thread(power_point); trd.Start(); }
        }
        void power_point()
        ...

As an answer to joshua-tristancho's question:
I don't know anything about powerpoint. But the process is the same as other file-handling.
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace myPowerPointHangs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private BackGroundWorker bgProcessPP = new BackGroundWorker();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadSettings();
        }

        private void LoadSettings()
        {
            bgProcessPP.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgProcessPP_DoWork);
            bgProcessPP.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bgProcessPP.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bgProcessPP.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bgProcessPP_RunWorkerCompleted);
            bgProcessPP.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgProcessPP_ProgressChanged);
        }

        private void bgProcessPP_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string fullSavePath = e.Argument;
            //You can insert your code from timer2_Tick in here
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer2.Stop();
            if(!bgProcessPP.IsBusy)
            {
                bgProcessPP.RunWorkerAsync(@"C:\myPowerPointHangs\mySlides.ppt");
            }
        }

        private void bgProcessPP_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Cancelled)
            {
                //Show message in a Label or MessageBox
            }
            else if(e.Error != null)
            {
                //Show some other error in a Label or MessageBox
            }
            else
            {
                 //Optional show a message when the backgroundworker is finished
            }
        }

        private void bgProcessPP_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Show the progress in a Label or calculate to a ProgressBar.
        }
    }
}

Hope this will help you to the right way. If there are some errors, my apologies. Having a few glasses of Whisky ;)
Oh, you are using System.Windows.Forms.Timer....There is also a System.Timers.Timer which runs in the background and will not hookup your form. But you have to use Innnvke...Inkoke...Invoke(new action(().. (Just fooling around ;))

Thanks Paul for taking the time to write a functional example but (1)BackGroundWorker is BackgroundWorker instead. (2)RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler requires RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs that leads me to your method bgProcessPP_RunWorkerCompleted uses RunWorkerCompleteEventArgs e, did you mean RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e. Finally (4)bgProcessPP_DoWork the e.Argument cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string', what about e.Argument.ToString(). Have you tested your code first? So, what advantages are in using BackgroundWorker over using traditional Thread?

Oh yes. It must be BackgroundWorker. And indeed, The RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs is missing a d and the Argument must be .ToString();. In my application I use the Argument to pass a int. So int idSupplier = Convert.ToInt32(e.Argument); No, I have not tested it. Just wrote it for you although I have a similar code in one of my projects which works good.
The advantage of a BackgroundWorker is that it's more simple and easier to reply from a working thread where by a Thread you must use delegates and events.
You can find al kinds of examples of the BackgroundWorker, Threads and async-await
